# Approach for installing system service implemented as Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, daemon, rhel

After years of being away from Ruby, I'm back full-force and have just cut my first gem, which includes an executable.  Everything works like a charm.

The problem I am facing, however, is that I ALSO have a startup script (not part of the gem istelf) that daemonizes the executable.  Additionally, I'd also like for the startup script to point the executable at configuration in a place like /var/

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way with rubygems, gemspec, etc., to specify files getting blown out to other parts of your system during install (e.g. startup script to /etc/init.d, and config to /var/).  It certainly wouldn't make sense if you COULD do that.

So... my question is... what IS the proper procedure for automating the installation of something like this.  I'm using RHEL, and am wondering if it's, perhaps, time for me to get my feet wet with making my first RPM.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a Ruby gem package copy files to arbitrary locations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367377/how-can-i-make-a-ruby-gem-package-copy-files-to-arbitrary-locations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** do it. However it is probably not quite the recommended approach. But yes it is possible to run arbitary code during gem installation using the `extensions` option.

From the [RubyGems Manual](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#extensions):

```
Usage
  spec.extensions << 'ext/rmagic/extconf.rb'

Notes
These files will be run when the gem is installed, causing the 
C (or whatever) code to be compiled on the user’s machine.
```

Just place whatever ruby code you need into the `extconf.rb` (or equivalent) file.

Examples for building C-extensions from the RubyGems Guides:
http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/

Comment: I can see why this wouldn't be recommended.  That seems practical for cases where native extensions need to be compiled.  It seems less practical for an installation process that should modify startup behavior.  Such a thing needs to be done by root or a sudoer anyway.  Still would love examples of a more kosher approach if anyone's got one.

Comment: @KentRancourt - If you look at the RubyGems package itself (download the source), you will see it contains a `setup.rb` file. That's what I see used in many cases. I.e. the "standard" ruby way is to run `ruby setup.rb` on ruby packages. That's kind of the equivalent of `"./configure; make install"` from the C-source world. The next is to create an RPM package, like you were thinking about already.

Comment: thanks!  This info puts me on the right track.  Much appreciated!