# How to add a (pre/post)_install_hook to ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hook

I want to execute some code at pre install time when installing a gem from rubygems.org with a command like `gem install some-gem`.

The documentation states that you can use a http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Gem.html pre_install hook that looks like this:

```
# File lib/rubygems.rb, line 724
def self.pre_install(&hook)
  @pre_install_hooks << hook
end
```

The doc further states:

> RubyGems defaults are stored in rubygems/defaults.rb. If you're packaging RubyGems or implementing Ruby you can change RubyGems' defaults.
>   For RubyGems packagers, provide lib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb and override any defaults from lib/rubygems/defaults.rb.
>   For Ruby implementers, provide lib/rubygems/defaults/#{RUBY_ENGINE}.rb and override any defaults from lib/rubygems/defaults.rb.
>   If you need RubyGems **to perform extra work on install or uninstall**, your defaults override file can set **pre and post install** and uninstall hooks. See ::pre_install, ::pre_uninstall, ::post_install, ::post_uninstall.

This sounds exactly what I want. So I created the files

- lib/rubygems/defaults/defaults.rb
- lib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
- rubygems/defaults.rb

and I put the code

```
Gem.pre_install { puts 'pre install hook called!' }
```

in all of the listed files. Then I added them to **require_paths** in the gemspec like this:

```
s.require_paths = ["lib", "test", "rubygems"]
```

But I see no output in the terminal when installing the gem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should 'I see now output' actually be 'I see no output'?

Comment: yes it should be "no" instead of "now". Edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is presently (2015-11-11) NO you cannot execute arbitrary code at install time *for a specific gem*.  The hooks mentioned in your question are for use by the RubyGem installer itself and are not gem specific.   See: [How can I make a Ruby gem package copy files to arbitrary locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367377/how-can-i-make-a-ruby-gem-package-copy-files-to-arbitrary-locations/33615052#) for additional details.

These files:

```
lib/rubygems/defaults/defaults.rb
lib/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
rubygems/defaults.rb
```

Are not called from your gem directory.  They are found in the RubyGems system location.

If you wish to execute the same code for every gem before any are installed then you can use the pre_install hooks by placing the code in `/usr/lib64/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/defaults.rb` or wherever your version of Ruby is installed on your system.  The `operating_system.rb` file will get loaded from the same location as well.

Comment: Changed the code to `Gem.pre_install { 
  puts 'pre install hook called!'
  return true
}`, but I get still no pre/post-install code executed. Even if the Gem::Installer would have been aborted, shouldn't the message be printed before? But I didn't see no nothin...

Comment: $ irb
`irb(main):001:0>  puts 'pre install hook called!' return true`  
`SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_return, expecting end-of-input`  
 `puts 'pre install hook called!' return true`

Comment: Maybe { puts( 'pre install hook called!' ) ; return true } would work?  or maybe a return from a block is creating a `LocalJumpError: unexpected return` which is being swallowed by the pre_install error handling?

Comment: There was a newline between `put` and `return` statements. I just couldn't paste the code correctly.

Comment: I replace the hook code in all potential hook file (defaults.rb, operating_system.rb, ...) with this code `Gem.pre_install { 
  system('echo "called from rubygems/defaults.rb" >> /tmp/status')
  return true
}
` but I see no file `/tmp/status` after installing the gem with `gem install gem-name`. This still doesn't work.

Comment: If everything sent to $STDOUT is being swallowed by the output method then the only thing that would show up without debug being turned on would be $STDERR. This assumes that RubyGem is not swallowing STDERR elsewhere as well. So, change the puts() in your original hook to warn() and see what you get on STDERR.

Comment: I replaced the signaling code with a command that creates a file in `/tmp`. So anybody can write to `/tmp`, but the code won't be executed. This the hook is never called.See comment before yours.

Comment: I have reread the API documentation.  One possible interpretation of the documentation is that the pre and post install hooks are meant to be used only for installing the RubyGem application itself and are provided for packagers of RubyGem shipped with a distribution.  I have asked about this on the Ruby-Users list and if I get a reply I will post it here.

Comment: Thank you! I achieved code execution via a native extension...If anybody want's to execute code after the gem is installed, place the code in the `extconf.rb` file and follow this tutorial: http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/

Answer (score 3):

You can add a native extension to the gem.

gemspec:    `s.extensions << 'path/to/extconf.rb'`

But then the `gem install` command want to execute a Makefile upon installation.

So the `extconf.rb` must create a dummy Makefile:

```
dummy_make_content = "make:\n" \
                     "\t:\n" \
                     "install:\n" \
                     "\t:\n" \
                     "clean:\n" \
                     "\t:\n"
File.write('Makefile', dummy_make_content)
```

Alternatively you can require the mkmf package and use a predefined function:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile ''
```